# How to put 403 page when user try to access a file directly?(.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

I am using apache server,consider this is my website: www.domain.com.

I saved my all my files,images,videos in sub-domain like-> http://sub.domain.com/file.jpg

I am acessing all files(i.e, image,videos) from sub-domain.

If any user tying to access my file directly in address bar(http://sub.domain.com/file.jpg), it should show 403 forbidden page.

If any user tying to access my website( www.domian.com ), it should allow to access.

I tried following .htaccess code,

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?sub.domain.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?sub.domain.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|avi|mp3|swf")$ - [F]
```

but the problem is, it also give 403 forbidden result, when i access my website.

**UPDATE:**

index.html in (domain.com)

```
 <html>
 <body>
   <h1>Example Page</h1>
   <img src="http://sub.domain.com/file.jpg">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Output: (when i trying to access "domain.com")

```
Example Page
```

image is not loading. it shows 403 forbidden in "console".

Answer (score 0):

`http://` won't be present in the referrer, only the domain name. Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|avi|mp3|swf)$ - [F]
```

Comment: What URL are you testing on? Does the entire page not load? Do you have any other rules?

Comment: That means the rule is working. You don't have a referrer of `sub.domain.com` so its showing forbidden. Try testing with curl or a REST console and manually set the referrer and see what happens.